# Handling deleted users in Zend PHP applications

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm coding a system that has a requirement to only "hide" a deleted user. In other words, the user is never deleted and all his actions in the system are not deleted to.
But, of course, the user has to be omitted in searches, has their login denied and so on...

I'm trying to do this by adding a column `inactive` in the `user` table in the database. And I'm filtering all the search results manually. But, I'm noticing that this coding pattern can be very dangerous and very complicated in the future, as the application grows.

I've worked with Ruby on Rails too, and there is a Gem/library called Act as Paranoid, that has exactly this behavior.

Do you know if there is any library that can handle this? Or the Zend Framework itself can have this behavior without manual control of the situation?

Any thoughts on this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use [ZEND Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html). There you can restrict access for users.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I'm not looking for a way to restrict access for users, this task is already done. I have to find a way to handle users that were deleted (by themselves, by moderators, and so on). These users are not truly deleted, but marked as deleted (DB column `deleted`). I've searched a bit about this and found something called 'soft-delete'. Do know something about this?

Comment: Ok, sorry for misinterpreting this.
Hm, a long story short: I agree with Pinal Dave when it comes to soft-delete - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/09/03/sql-server-soft-delete-isdelete-column-your-opinion/ - It will save you a lot of pain in my eyes to simply backup the entries and then delete them.

Comment: In certain situations I agree with him too. But, in this specific project, I have to code based on requirement documents created by the client. But thanks anyway for your time!

Comment: Ok, when I had to use soft-delete, I'd expand the ZEND-Auth (or whatever you are using) with a handleSoftDeletes() where I'd simply check for this column. That'd be my first approach.